# fitcdiscr function in MatLab

Tags: matlab, sas

I'm attempting to use the fitcdiscr class to reproduce SAS results, but I'm evidently not using the function correctly.  I've been through the MatLab documentation on the subject repeatedly, but can't seem to figure out what I'm specifying incorrectly.  I'll first post the data, then the SAS code that is specifying the correct linear discriminant functions, then the MatLab code that I'm struggling with.  Any help would be appreciated.

Data:

```
a 191 131 53
a 185 134 50
a 200 137 52
a 173 127 50
a 171 128 49
a 160 118 47
a 188 134 54
a 186 129 51
a 174 131 52
a 163 115 47
b 186 107 49
b 211 122 49
b 201 144 47
b 242 131 54
b 184 108 43
b 211 118 51
b 217 122 49
b 223 127 51
b 208 125 50
b 199 124 46
```

SAS:

```
options ls=78;
title "Discrimant Analysis - Insect Data";
data insect;
infile "C:\Users\Zach\Documents\Classes\Penn State\STAT 505\Data\insect.txt";
input species $ joint1 joint2 aedeagus;
run;
data test;
input joint1 joint2 aedeagus;
cards;
194 124 49
;
proc discrim data=insect pool=test crossvalidate testdata=test testout=a;
class species;
var joint1 joint2 aedeagus;
run;
proc print;
run;
```

MatLab:

```
path = 'C:\Users\Zach\Documents\Classes\Penn State\STAT 505\Data';
file = 'insect.txt';

fid = fopen(fullfile(path,file));
X = textscan(fid, '%s%f%f%f','Delimiter');
fclose(fid); clear fid

data = cell2mat(X(:,2:4));%data
grps = X{:,1};%group a or b
prednames = {'joint 1', 'joint 2', 'aedeagus'};

M = fitcdiscr(data,grps,'PredictorNames',prednames,...
    'Prior','uniform','DiscrimType','linear');
```

The linear functions are specified using variants of

```
M.Coeffs(1,2).Linear  and  M.Coeffs(1,2).Const
```

The two functions I'm expecting are:

da = -247 -1.4x1 + 1.5x2 10.9x3

db = -193 - .74x1 + 1.1x2 + 8.3x3

Thanks for the help.

Edit:

Using "Applied Multivariate Statistical Analysis, 6th ed" by Johnson and Wichern, section 11.3, I've produced the following code that gives me the SAS results:

```
xbar = M.Mu;
S = M.Sigma;
Sinv = inv(S);
for ii = 1:2
    d0(ii,:) = -1/2*xbar(ii,:)*Sinv*xbar(ii,:)';
    d(ii,:) = xbar(ii,:)*Sinv;
end
```

I'm still left wondering just what fitcdiscr is doing.

Comment: So I still haven't been able to figure out what MatLab is doing in the fitcdiscr function; however, I've been able to reproduce the results obtained in SAS.

I've added the new MatLab code as an edit

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with `fitcdiscr`. I have the most basic example data and I'm following the MatLab doc with no success. I think something is either wrong with the function or docs. Most likely the latter.

Comment: I wrote a couple of custom functions to do what I wanted to do since I haven't been able to solve the problem/figure out fitdiscr.  Depending on what you are looking to do, I can share them with you (when I can access the computer that they are on).

Comment: I appreciate the offer, but I really needed to solve the problem in MatLab. I ended up finding other, more explicit, solutions. I'm still very surprised`fitcdiscr` doesn't work as the documentation suggests.